# How to navigate from login to home page with Firebase flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

In the welcome screen, I have two button which is login and register. For the first time, when i try to login to the login screen, it did not navigate to the Home Page. For the second try, I want to login again, it can't back to the login page (stuck at Welcome Screen). Can anyone help me? Thank you

Welcome Screen Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class WelcomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WelcomeScreenState createState() => _WelcomeScreenState();
}

class _WelcomeScreenState extends State<WelcomeScreen> {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;


  navigateToLogin() async {
    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "Login");
  }

  navigateToRegister() async {
    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "SignUp");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: 35.0),
            Container(
              height: 400,
              child: Image(
                image: AssetImage("assets/girlsave.png"),
                fit: BoxFit.contain,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            RichText(
                text: TextSpan(
                    text: 'Welcome to ',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 25.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.orange),
                    children: <TextSpan>[
                      TextSpan(
                          text: 'MONGER!',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 30.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.orange))
                    ])),
            SizedBox(height: 10.0),
            Text(
              'Your Personal Money Tracker',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 30.0),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                RaisedButton(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30),
                    onPressed: navigateToLogin,
                    child: Text(
                      'LOGIN',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    ),
                    color: Colors.orange),
                SizedBox(width: 20.0),
                RaisedButton(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30),
                    onPressed: navigateToRegister,
                    child: Text(
                      'REGISTER',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    ),
                    color: Colors.orange),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20.0),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Login Page Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:monger_app/WelcomeScreen/signup.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  String _email, _password;

  checkAuthentification() async {
    _auth.authStateChanges().listen((user) {
      if (user != null) {
        print(user);

        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/");
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.checkAuthentification();
  }

  login() async {
    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      _formKey.currentState.save();

      try {
        await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: _email, password: _password);
      } catch (e) {
        showError(e.message);
        print(e);
      }
    }
  }

  showError(String errormessage) {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text('ERROR'),
            content: Text(errormessage),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                  child: Text('OK'))
            ],
          );
        });
  }

  navigateToSignUp() async {
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignUpPage()));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          brightness: Brightness.light,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          leading: IconButton(
            onPressed: (){
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios,
              size: 20,
              color: Colors.black,),
          ),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  height: 400,
                  child: Image(
                    image: AssetImage("assets/girlsave.png"),
                    fit: BoxFit.contain,
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: Form(
                    key: _formKey,
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          child: TextFormField(
                              validator: (input) {
                                if (input.isEmpty) return 'Enter Email';
                              },
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  labelText: 'Email',
                                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email)),
                              onSaved: (input) => _email = input),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: TextFormField(
                              validator: (input) {
                                if (input.length < 6)
                                  return 'Provide Minimum 6 Character';
                              },
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                labelText: 'Password',
                                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock),
                              ),
                              obscureText: true,
                              onSaved: (input) => _password = input),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 20),
                        RaisedButton(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(70, 10, 70, 10),
                          onPressed: login,
                          child: Text('LOGIN',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 20.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                          color: Colors.orange,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  child: Text('Create an Account?'),
                  onTap: navigateToSignUp,
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Sign Up code:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';



class SignUpPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignUpPageState createState() => _SignUpPageState();
}

class _SignUpPageState extends State<SignUpPage> {
  FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  String _username, _email, _password;

  checkAuthentication() async {
    _auth.authStateChanges().listen((user) async {
      if (user != null) {
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/");
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.checkAuthentication();
  }

  signUp() async {
    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      _formKey.currentState.save();

      try {
        UserCredential user = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: _email, password: _password);
        if (user != null) {
          // UserUpdateInfo updateuser = UserUpdateInfo();
          // updateuser.displayName = _name;
          //  user.updateProfile(updateuser);
          await _auth.currentUser.updateProfile(displayName: _username);
          // await Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context,"/") ;

        }
      } catch (e) {
        showError(e.message);
        print(e);
      }
    }
  }

  showError(String errormessage) {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text('ERROR'),
            content: Text(errormessage),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                  child: Text('OK'))
            ],
          );
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          brightness: Brightness.light,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          leading: IconButton(
            onPressed: (){
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios,
              size: 20,
              color: Colors.black,),
          ),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  height: 400,
                  child: Image(
                    image: AssetImage("assets/girlsave.png"),
                    fit: BoxFit.contain,
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: Form(
                    key: _formKey,
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          child: TextFormField(
                              validator: (input) {
                                if (input.isEmpty) return 'Enter Username';
                              },
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                labelText: 'Username',
                                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person),
                              ),
                              onSaved: (input) => _username = input),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: TextFormField(
                              validator: (input) {
                                if (input.isEmpty) return 'Enter Email';
                              },
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  labelText: 'Email',
                                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email)),
                              onSaved: (input) => _email = input),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: TextFormField(
                              validator: (input) {
                                if (input.length < 6)
                                  return 'Provide Minimum 6 Character';
                              },
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                labelText: 'Password',
                                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock),
                              ),
                              obscureText: true,
                              onSaved: (input) => _password = input),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 20),
                        RaisedButton(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(70, 10, 70, 10),
                          onPressed: signUp,
                          child: Text('SignUp',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 20.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                          color: Colors.orange,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Main Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:monger_app/WelcomeScreen/login.dart';
import 'package:monger_app/WelcomeScreen/signup.dart';
import 'package:monger_app/WelcomeScreen/welcome_screen.dart';
import 'package:monger_app/page/root.dart';
import 'package:monger_app/theme/colors.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(

      theme: ThemeData(
          primaryColor: primary
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home:

      WelcomeScreen(),

      routes: <String,WidgetBuilder>{

        "Login" : (BuildContext context)=>LoginPage(),
        "SignUp":(BuildContext context)=>SignUpPage(),
        "start":(BuildContext context)=>Root(),
      },

    );
  }

}
```

HomePage Code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_icons/flutter_icons.dart';
import 'package:monger_app/page/setting.dart';
import 'package:monger_app/theme/colors.dart';
import 'package:animated_bottom_navigation_bar/animated_bottom_navigation_bar.dart';
import 'package:monger_app/page/transaction.dart';
import 'package:monger_app/page/statistics.dart';
import 'package:monger_app/page/account.dart';
import 'package:monger_app/page/record.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class Root extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RootState createState() => _RootState();
}

class _RootState extends State<Root> {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  User user;
  bool isloggedin = false;

  checkAuthentification() async {
    _auth.authStateChanges().listen((user) {
      if (user == null) {
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed("start");
      }
    });
  }
  int pageIndex = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: getBody(),
      bottomNavigationBar: getFooter(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: (){
          setTabs(4);
        },
          child: Icon(Icons.add, size: 25),
          backgroundColor: primary,
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
    );
  }
  Widget getBody(){
    return IndexedStack(
      index: pageIndex,
      children: [
        Transaction(),
        Statistics(),
        Account(),
        Settings(),
        Record()
      ],
    );

  }
  Widget getFooter(){
    List<IconData> iconItems = [
      Ionicons.md_bookmarks,
      Ionicons.md_stats,
      Ionicons.md_wallet,
      Ionicons.ios_settings,
    ];
    return AnimatedBottomNavigationBar(
        activeColor: primary,
        splashColor: secondary,
        inactiveColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
        icons: iconItems,
        activeIndex: pageIndex,
        gapLocation: GapLocation.center,
        notchSmoothness: NotchSmoothness.softEdge,
        leftCornerRadius: 10,
        iconSize: 25,
        rightCornerRadius: 10,
        onTap: (index) {
          setTabs(index);
      });
  }
  setTabs(index) {
    setState(() {
      pageIndex = index;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this code:

```dart
  Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/");
```

but you do not have the named route "/" registered.

From your code, your Home Page is registered as "start".
So you should update the name of the route to "start" and that should work.

Your updated code should be as below:

```dart
  Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "start");
```